# Data Validation dropdown in standard excel form

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using an excel built-in data entry form for a table, and I would like to get the same data validation dropdowns from the table in the form. Is this possible?

If vba is the answer, how do I get the form fields in vba to add the proper conditions?

Thanks!!!

Comment: The built-in data entry form is not customizable.  To add data validation, you would need to insert a user form into your project. Then you can add combo boxes or perform validation using events, etc.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please be more explicit, show us what you did. At a high level, you can get the look up values, use a hidden sheet, and ranges from that hidden sheet as dropdown list candidates for data validation

Comment: @dgorti , I'm using the built-in form provided by Excel for a table (range). No vba yet, and apparently it is not customizable, so I will build my own form in vba. Thanks for your answers

Comment: Thanks @tlemaster. I will build my own vba form then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Excel built-in data entry form is not customizable